Cannot Produce Baseline on Cloud for Visual Tests
I'm using Cypress and Github-Actions together. I'm using "cypress-image-diff-js" plugin to take care of comparing and testing visuals and test whether image is correct or not. These libraries are generate "baseline" folder at first execution. On continous executions after first; it compares the image with baselined image (that's the logic).
My problem here is I cannot fully utilize it on cloud (github-actions):

If I generate baseline image on my local and put it to cloud and execute it; after first execution it says baseline image and executed test image has difference in x% difference.
If I do not put any baseline image and try cloud to generate its baseline image on first execution, I cannot find any baseline image on github repo (probably it is not generated).

What is the best way to do visual tests on cloud side such as github actions?
Thanks!
